# How to force CLion using a custom MSVC version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, clion

## The problem

I use CLion 2022.2, Visual Studio 2022, and CMake 3.23. I want to use the toolset of version 14.31.17.1, which is older than the newest one.

## Configure

I configure the CMake project with a `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
project(test_project)
add_executable(test_project main.cpp)
```

In CLion, I specify generator Visual Studio 2022 and a toolset 14.31.17.1. The command executed is

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T version=14.31.17.1 -S F:\test_project -B F:\test_project\build
```

Nevertheless, logs say

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31629.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31629.0
```

When I clear the cache directory and execute the same command in CLion Terminal (copy and paste it with the `.` or `&` prefix), I get what I want

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.31107.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.31107.0
```

Note: toolset 14.31.31103 contains MSVC 19.31.31107.0 while toolset 14.33.31629 contains MSVC 19.33.31629.0. So I conclude that something goes wrong.

After this, I can modify the project and execute the "Reload CMake Project", and CLion does it well because the versions of compilers are already configured.

Specifying C and C++ compilers for the toolchain (File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains) doesn't help.

When I remove the latest toolset using Visual Studio Installer, it also automatically removes C++ CMake Tools for Windows, which doesn't allow me to use CMake with Visual Studio.

## Build

My `main.cpp` file is

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << _MSC_VER << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I configure the project (no matter with CLion or manually) and build it using CLion GUI, I get the answer

```
1933
```

Although, if I use the same command as CLion, namely

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --build F:\test_project\build --target test_project --config Debug
```

I get what I need

```
1931
```

The strange part is that I get the correct result using Terminal even after configuring the project using CLion GUI. Also, I can set up the project in Terminal to use the newer toolset (which is the default) and have the `1933` printed.

Also, when I debug the code using CLion, the Evaluate says that `_MSC_VER` is `1933` but the application still prints `1931`. When I create a variable `int x{_MSC_VER};`, the debugger shows that `x` equals `1931`.

## Summary

If I use CLion GUI to configure or build the project or to do both things, it uses MSVC 19.33.31629.0.
If I configure and build the project in CLion's Terminal using the same commands CLion shows me when configuring and building the project, I can use MSVC 19.31.31107.0.

Am I missing something? Does CLion specify environment variables I should override? Is it possible to choose the MSVC version I need using CLion?